# How to hide view which contains activity indicator when it isn not shown

Tags: react-native, activity-indicator

I have the following situation: I created the `View` where `ActivityIndicator` is placed:

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-around', padding: 10 }}>
  <ActivityIndicator animating={this.props.isLoading} size="large" color="#0000ff" />
</View>
```

And the problem is that when `ActivityIndicator` is hidden, `View` is still shown. So, how can I hide this view after hiding `ActivityIndicator`. or maybe there is any other way how can I remove this empty place, where was loading indicator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix will be:

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-around', padding: this.props.isLoading ? 10 : 0 }}>
  <ActivityIndicator animating={this.props.isLoading} size="large" color="#0000ff" />
</View>
```

But try to do something like:

```
renderLoader() {
  if (this.props.isLoading) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-around', padding: 10}}>
        <ActivityIndicator animating={this.props.isLoading} size="large" color="#0000ff" />
      </View>
    );
  }
  return null;
}
```

Or just change the implementation to:

```
{this.props.isLoading ? 
  <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-around', padding: 10}}>
        <ActivityIndicator animating={this.props.isLoading} size="large" color="#0000ff" />
      </View> 
: null}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but can you explain where should I add this function? In screen class or where? I have some other views, so, as I understand, I can't add body of this function to render. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @SergeiMikhailovskii For loader always create another file as shown above.            
  for ex. export default class loader extends Component {  // code from above   }      and pass the props isLoading for this file to show/hide the indicator